# How do I generate this specific project structure with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, build-system

How would a CMakeList file for generating the following project structure look?
I can't seem to figure out how to configure the location on output project files, and splitting sub-projects and solution files from visual studio.

```
Project/
    Binaries/
        Project.exe
    Intermediate/
        CMakeFiles/
            ...
        VisualStudio/
            Project.vcxproj
            Project.vcxproj.filters
            Project.vcxproj.user
    Source/
        MySource.cpp
        MySource.h
    Project.sln
    CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: Fyi, you generally don't use CMake to *build* previously existing Visual C++ solutions/projects; you use it to *generate* them (then build them afterward via `cmake --build` as desired. Are you asking how to distribute subdirectory CMakeLists.txt's so such an architecture works?

Comment: I'd advise for: 1) reading about CMake project structure (there are some good books out there, Craig Scott's Professional CMake and Rafal Swidzinski's Modern CMake for C++ to cite two); 2) start with a small example (that `Source` folder alone), then add complexity (a project each time); 3) check GitHub for examples; I know there are zillions, but you'll end up finding some of them very useful (e.g. https://github.com/foonathan/memory).

Comment: My problem is not using CMake, my problem is configuring it to work with our pipeline. Specifically, I need both CMakeFiles and Visual Studio sub-projects to go in the folder illustrated above. I can't seem to find the right documentation explaining this. I know how CMake works, but I need some help with the configuration, because of the very vague, to non-existing documentation.

Comment: Address them as two different problems. Visual Studio solution and project files and binaries can live under the same root folder as CMake files and binaries. So get one working (e.g. VS), then get the other one working. You can do VS configuration through the IDE and CMake configuration through the CMakeLists.txt files, CMakePresets.json and so on.

Comment: Afaik it's impossible to have cmake generate the toplevel solution in a directory that doesn't contain the `CMakeFiles` directory too. The other requirements shouldn't be hard to achieve... I strongly advise against overlapping the build directory with the source directories btw... Why does the location of the project files matter anyways? You'll probably add the build directory to `.gitignore`. A solution generated by cmake cannot be transfered between pcs or even between different locations of the same PC.

Comment: @fabian, We are transitioning from a custom in-house build system, we don't want to change the project structure since it works quite well for us.